# Why is this function parameter identical in every invocation, despite passing different value? (Creating closures in a loop)

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, closures, pytorch, local-variables

I'm using PyTorch and trying to register hooks on model parameters. The following code creates lambda functions to add to each model parameter, so I can see in the hook which tensor the gradient belongs to

```
import torch
import torchvision

# define model and random train batch
model = torchvision.models.alexnet()
input = torch.rand(10, 3, 224, 224)   # batch of 10 images
targets = torch.zeros(10).long()

def grad_hook_template(param, name, grad):
    print(f'Receive grad for {name} w whape {grad.shape}')

# add one lambda hook to each parameter
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    print(f'Register hook for {name}')

    # use a lambda so we can pass additional information to the hook, which should only take one parameter
    param.register_hook(lambda grad: grad_hook_template(param, name, grad))

loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
optimizer.zero_grad()

prediction = model(input)
loss = loss_fn(prediction, targets)
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

The result is that the `name` and `param` arguments to `grad_hook_template` always as the same value (and `id`), but the `grad` argument is always different (as expected). Why is it that when I register the hook, the lambdas seem to refer to the same local variables each time?

I read e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2295368/2397253) that loops do not create new scopes and closures are lexical in Python, i.e. the `name` and `param` which I'm passing to the lambda are just pointers and whatever value they have at the end of the loop is seen by everyone with this pointer. But what can I do about it? `copy.copy()` the variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've run into *late binding closures*. The variables `param` and `name` are looked up at call time, not when the function they're used in is defined. By the time any of these functions are called, `name` and `param` are at the last values in the loop. To get around this, you could do this:

```
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    print(f'Register hook for {name}')
    param.register_hook(lambda grad, name=name, param=param: grad_hook_template(param, name, grad))
```

However, I think using `functools.partial` is the right solution here:

```
from functools import partial

for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    print(f'Register hook for {name}')
    param.register_hook(partial(grad_hook_template, name=name, param=param))
```

You can find more information about [late binding closures at the Common Gotchas page of the Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures) as well as [in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result).

**Note that this applies equally to functions defined with the `def` keyword.**

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of answered by the [FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result).

Solutions include

- using `functools.partial` instead of `lambda`
- using default params to the lambdas to capture the value of the variables